# Jquery, changing color on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This has been driving me crazy for a while, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to make a 4x4 grid and change the color of each square when I hover my mouse over (the color stays after the mouse leaves) but the changing color part is not working. 
Here is what I have so far:

[Changing color on hover:](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfKM8/)

This is the part where I am stuck

```
$('.square').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: thank you for your responses everyone, I will keep in mind event delegation the next time I fill the DOM dynamically.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove your jquery code for adding class hover and just make this css change in the file

```
.square:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

simply fixes your problem in pure Css.

Adding JsFiddle for this
http://jsfiddle.net/jjeswin/nb3dB/1/

Comment: +1 IMO, this should be the correct answer since it solves the problem in the best possible way even though OP uses jQuery to do the same.

Comment: @ limelights - but he wants answer in jquery not css

Comment: @sudharsan No, OP wants the correct answer and a solution to his problem - currently he's using jQuery to try and fix it.

Comment: thank you but i want the color to stay on even after i finished hovering over the square. To my knowledge there isnt a .selector:unhover in css

Answer (score 2):

You need to first call `makeGrid(4);` and then bind the event.

also to remove class you need to modify hover function to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` function:

```
makeGrid(4);
$('.square').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
},function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2zcxP/)**

**Update: for keeping the color even after mouseleave**:

```
 makeGrid(4);
      makeGrid(4);
 $('.square').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
 });
```

**[Demo with only mouseenter](http://jsfiddle.net/5pvJ2/)**

Comment: _event delegation_ is better than sequence of function call then event binding

Comment: I agree to that... but he is rendering small static html with nothing from any service call. so its ensured that dom is getting rendered before hover method is binding the event. then why complicate the functionality using delegation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#container').on("mouseenter", '.square', function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');  
});

$('#container').on("mouseleave", '.square', function() {
$(this).removeClass('hover');   
});
```

Use event delegation for dynamically created elements.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/m6Bnz/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R6Bt6/ Note: For performance point of view use `#container` in place of `document`

Answer (score 1):

Use `event delegation` for added dom elements dynamically . it is the best way to do

```
$('#container').on('mouseenter' , ".square" , function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');

    });
/* $('#container').on('mouseleave' , ".square" , function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');

    }); */
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfKM8/8/)

Comment: the color to stay on even after i finished hovering over the square try the demo

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the fiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/ZfKM8/5/

In your javascript, i've removed the hover function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function makeGrid(n) {
        var grid = $('#container');
        for (var i = 1;i<=n; i++) {
            for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++){
                grid.append("<div class='square'></div>");
            }
            grid.append("<div class='new_row'></div>");
        }
    };  
    makeGrid(4);
});
```

in your css, instead of .hover change it to .square:hover

```
.square:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your boxes created dynamically to the DOM, the hover event will not be available for these boxes. In this case, event delegation will help you to attach that event

Try this

OP said `the color stays after the mouse leaves`

```
$('#container').on('mouseenter','.square',function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfKM8/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {



    function makeGrid(n) {
        var grid = $('#container');
        for (var i = 1;i<=n; i++) {
            for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++){
                grid.append("<div class='square'></div>");
            }
            grid.append("<div class='new_row'></div>");
        }
    };
    makeGrid(4);
    $(document).on('mouseenter','.square',function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    });
    $(document).on('mouseleave','.square',function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });



});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you're not using CSS for this?

```
.square:hover { color: #superAwesome }
```

If you want the color to animate (and delay when mousing out) you can use CSS3 transition:

```
.square { transition: color 1s; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            <html>
        <head>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <style>

        .hover
        {
        background:red;
        }
        </style>


        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="square" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid"> </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        $('.square').hover(function() 
        {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        });


        $('.square').mouseout(function() 
        {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
        });
        </script>


        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `.toggleClass()`:

```
makeGrid(4);

$('.square').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');   
});
```